# writing infix to postfix, cannot tell why my code is throwing an out of bounds exception

Tags: java, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am trying to do this without using java's built in stack, so i made a class with functions (listed below). I cannot figure out for the life of me where my mistake in logic causes the error.

```
package ass5;
import java.util.*;

public class ass5main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ass5methods pfix = new ass5methods();

        HashMap<Character, Integer> compare = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        compare.put('-',1);
        compare.put('+',1);
        compare.put('*',2);
        compare.put('/',2);
        compare.put('(', 3);
        compare.put('{', 3);

        HashMap<Integer, String> errorMsg = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
        errorMsg.put(0, "bracket does not match");
        errorMsg.put(1, "parethenses do not match");
        errorMsg.put(2, "order of brackets and parentheses is mixed");
        errorMsg.put(3, "please hardcode an input");

        String[] Statement = new String[5];
        Statement[0] = "(1-1)";
        Statement[1] = "(2+3)";
        Statement[2] = "(3x9) {2+4}";
        Statement[3] = "(2(3*6)}";
        Statement[4] = "{34(26)+10-3}";

        for (Integer i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            String postt = "";
            if(Statement[i]!=null) {
                String expression = Statement[i]; 
                boolean correct = true;
                System.out.println("expression" + (i +1));
                for (Integer j = 0; j < expression.length() && correct ; j++) {
                    char c = expression.charAt(j); 
                    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                        postt +=c;
                    }
                    if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' ) {
                        if (pfix.stackTop == -1 || compare.get(pfix.read()) <= compare.get(c)) {
                            pfix.push(c);
                        }
                        else if(pfix.stackTop > -1 && compare.get(pfix.read()) >= compare.get(c)){
                            postt += pfix.pop();
                            pfix.push(c);
                        }       }       
                    else if (c == '(' || c == '{' ) {
                        pfix.push(c);
                    }

                    if(c == ')') {
//This while loop is where eclipse says the error is
                        while(!((pfix.topOfStack()) == '(')) {
                            postt += pfix.pop(); 
                        }
                        pfix.pop();
                    }
                    else if(c == '}') {
                        while(!(pfix.read() == '{')) {
                            postt += pfix.pop(); 
                        }
                        pfix.pop();
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(postt);
        }
    }
}
package ass5;
import java.util.*;

public class ass5methods {

    int stackTop;
    public ArrayList <Character> stack2;

    public ass5methods() {
        stackTop = -1;
        stack2 = new ArrayList <Character>();
    }
    public void push(Character c) {
        stackTop++;
        stack2.add(c);
    }   
    public char pop() {

        char c3 = stack2.remove(stackTop);
        stackTop--;
        return c3;
    }
    public char topOfStack() {

        char c = stack2.get(stackTop);
        return c;
    }
    public char read() {
        char c = stack2.get(stackTop);
        return c;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (stackTop<0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Causes the error at what line of code?

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Character> operators = new Stack();

    HashMap<Character, Integer> compare = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    compare.put('-',1);
    compare.put('+',1);
    compare.put('*',2);
    compare.put('/',2);
    compare.put('(', 3);
    compare.put('{', 3);

    HashMap<Integer, String> errorMsg = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    errorMsg.put(0, "bracket does not match");
    errorMsg.put(1, "parathenses does not match");
    errorMsg.put(2, "order of brackets and paranthese is mixed");
    errorMsg.put(3, "please hardcode an input");

    String[] Statement = new String[5];
    Statement[0] = "(1-1)";
    Statement[1] = "(2+3)";
    Statement[2] = "(3*9) {2+4}";
    Statement[3] = "(2*(3*6)}";
     Statement[4] = "{34*(26)+10-3}";

    for (Integer i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        String postt = "";
        if(Statement[i]!=null) {
            String expression = Statement[i];
            boolean correct = true;
            System.out.println("expression" + (i +1));
            for (Integer j = 0; j < expression.length() && correct ; j++) {
                char c = expression.charAt(j);
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                    postt +=c;
                }
                if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '(' || c == '{' ) {
                    operators.push(c);
                }
                if(c == ')' || c == '}')  {
                    while(!operators.isEmpty()) {
                        char op = operators.pop();
                        if(op == '(' || op == '{' ) {
                            break;
                        }
                        postt += op;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(postt);
    }
}
```

It's not a complete solution, I changed it to print postfix of expression. I have used the Stack lib class. you can update to your choices. Just updated on top of your implementation. This will help you to develop better. May be use can try the problems this way.

1. understand the problem.
2. write test cases
3. write your logic on paper.
4. validate your test cases with your logic.
5. convert it into code.

Comment: while writing infix use proper notation. a(b) is not equal to a*b, or you can define your own rules and implement to support them.

Comment: You didn't identify the OP's actual problem, or show where in your code you solved it, and how. You just posted a code dump with no explanation.